# How to check Unicode input value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow the user to input only *Khmer character* (Unicode character) and raise an alert if otherwise.

```
Khmer Name: <input type="text" class="namekh" name="namekh">
```

In order to do so, my sample script is like this:

```
<script>
  var namekh = $('.namekh').val();

  // function to check unicode or not
  if (isUnicodeFunc(namekh) == true) {
    alert('unicode character');
  } else {
    alert('please enter unicode only');
  }
</script>
```

How can I define function `isUnicodeFunc` to detect if the value is Unicode or not?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_alphabet), the Khmer alphabet is unicode range 0x1780 to 0x17FF and 0x19E0 to 0x19FF, so you can simply test that all the characters in the string are in that range: https://jsfiddle.net/8o87jgys/1/

```
function isUnicodeFunc(string) {
    let isKhmer = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let code = string.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code < 0x1780 || (code > 0x17FF && code < 0x19E0) || code > 0x19FF) {
            isKhmer = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isKhmer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the input with a regex.

```
var myRegex  = new RegExp('[ក-\u17fe᧠-᧾]', 'gi');;

function isKhmerChar(textInput){
    return myRegex.test(textInput);
}
```

There are tools from where you can get the regular expression like [Unicode range RegExp generator](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#), this one works for javascript unicode characters.

[RegExp MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

[RegExp.prototype.test() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx for a simple solution. See the first function which will test if a given string contains only Khmer characters. [Here is an explanation, what is matched with the following RegEx rule.](https://regex101.com/r/UMwVHv/1)

```js
function checkKhmerCharacters( val ) {
  // Khmer range found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_alphabet
  return /^[\u1780-\u17FF\u19E0-\u19FF]$/.test( val );
}

// Validate as you type
$( 'input' ).on( 'input', function ( e ) {
  const elm = $( this );
  const isValid = checkKhmerCharacters( e.target.value );
  elm.toggleClass( 'input-error', !isValid );
} );

$( 'button' ).on( 'click', () => {
  var namekh = $('.namekh').val();
  console.log( checkKhmerCharacters( namekh ) );

  if( checkKhmerCharacters( namekh ) ) {
    alert( 'unicode character' );
  }
  else {
    alert( 'please enter unicode only' );
  }
} );
```

```css
.input-error {
  border: red 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Khmer Name: <input type="text" class="namekh" name="namekh"> <button>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [unicode table](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/sites/utf.ru/tables/khmer.html) you have to check if a string has a charackter with the charcode between `0x1780` to `0x17FF` or `0x19e0` to `0x19FF`.
You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string to receive an array. This array you can loop with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). `some()` will break the loop if a condition returns false - so you don't have to loop through the whole array

### Code

```
function containsOnlyKahmerCharakter(str) {
  return str.split('').some(function(char) {
    var charCode = char.charCodeAt('0')
    return (
      charCode >= 0x1780 && charCode <= 0x17FF 
      || charCode >= 0x19e0 && charCode <= 0x19FF
    )
  })
}
```

### Example

```js
function containsOnlyKahmerCharakter(str) {
  return str.split('').some(function(char) {
    var charCode = char.charCodeAt('0')
    return (
      charCode >= 0x1780 && charCode <= 0x17FF 
      || charCode >= 0x19e0 && charCode <= 0x19FF
    )
  })
}

console.log(containsOnlyKahmerCharakter('ក ខ គ ឃ ង ច'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use regular expressions with [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) and [Unicode flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags). (ES2018)

```js
/^\p{scx=Khmer}+$/u.test(namekh)
```

Entire script:

```js
var namekh = document.querySelector('.namekh').value;

if (/^\p{scx=Khmer}+$/u.test(namekh)) {
  alert('unicode character');
} else {
  alert('please enter unicode only');
}
```