# How to check Unicode ranges requiring more than 4 character length using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, unicode-string, fromcharcode

Following the question [How to check Unicode input value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803594/how-to-check-unicode-input-value-in-javascript), I noticed that Unicode character ranges having more than 4 character length (for example [Grantha Unicode Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grantha_(Unicode_block)) cannot be captured using the following code;

```
function checkGrantha(str) {
  return str.split('').some(function(char) {
    var charCode = char.charCodeAt('0')
    return (
      charCode >= 0x11300 && charCode <= 0x1137F 
    )
}) 
}

console.log('');
```

After some research I found this [article](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/) where it says that ES6/ES2015 introduced a way to represent Unicode points in the astral planes (any Unicode code point requiring more than 4 chars), by wrapping the code in graph parentheses:
'\u{XXXXX}', example '\u{1F436}';

But this cannot be implemented in the above provided code. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, don't use the `str.split('')` function, it will split the string into 16-bit code units, and this will work incorrectly for characters outside the BMP (i.e., in astral planes); use `Array.from(str)` instead...
- Next, for a similar reason, don't use `char.charCodeAt(0)`, but `char.codePointAt(0)` instead...

```
function checkGrantha(str)
{
    return Array.from(str).some(function(char) {
    var codePoint = char.codePointAt(0)
    return (
        codePoint >= 0x11300 && codePoint <= 0x1137F
    )
}) 
}
```

- Another possibility would be to use a simple regular expression with the 'u' flag:

```
function checkGrantha(str)
{
    return /[\u{11300}-\u{1137F}]/u.test(str);
}
```

or:

```
function checkGrantha(str)
{
    // Warning: this will miss U+1133B COMBINING BINDU BELOW whose Unicode 'Script' property is 'Inherited', not 'Grantha'...
    return /\p{Script=Grantha}/u.test(str);
}
```

```
console.log (checkGrantha('')); // -> true
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I reckon that the regex function is more compact and faster. :)